# Openssl: cat: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, openssl

I try to create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) using

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key domain.key -subj "/" \ -reqexts SAN -config <(cat /System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf \ <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:foo.com,DNS:www.foo.com"))
```

but getting the following error message

```
cat: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory
unknown option -reqexts
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Macbooks are not servers within the meaning of Server Fault.

Comment: i get the same error on my ubuntu server on azure

Comment: I'm sure it does, especially as this pathname `/System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf` doesn't exist on Ubuntu ;)

Comment: This question should be re-opened.  It's perfectly applicable to "information technology systems in a business environment".  @Thetimehascome If you read the question, you'd see that the path to `openssl.cnf` isn't the hangup here.

Answer (score 4):

Notice the difference between `/dev/fd/63` and  `/dev/fd/63`. The extra space matters. `/dev/fd/63` is an absolute path which would work. Whereas
 `/dev/fd/63` is a relative path. Probably your current directory does not contain a subdirectory named .

The space is in the name because that is what you asked for. The part of the command to pay attention to is this: `\ <(`.

The sequence `\`  is an escaped space and `<(` is used to run a subshell with output to a pipe.

So what happens is this.

1. The subshell is started with stdout pointing to a pipe.
2. The name of the reading end of that pipe happens to be `/dev/fd/63`
3. The shell prepends a space to that name as you asked for.
4. The shell calls `cat` with the file name  `/dev/fd/63`, which does not exist.
5. `cat` reports an error.

Removing `\`  from the command will surely make that error message go away.

Comment: And similarly `\ -reqexts` producing `(SPACE)-reqexts` as an option argument, which is wrong